# External javascprit function not working

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I'm trying to load the map1() function in my html file but it's not loading

This is the html. If I put it under one html file it works fine ,but now that I have a separate html and js file it won't work.

```
<html>
<head>
     <script src="map.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map">

  </div>
  <script>
        map1();
  </script>
</body >
```

The js is this.

```
function map1() {

              var locations = [
                  ['Rye Hall', 53.384915, -6.598975 ],
                  ['Auxilla',53.384168, -6.598228 ],
                  ['Education House', 53.383348, -6.597810 ],


                  ['Gym', 53.384759, -6.603737 ],
                  ['Students Union', 53.383056, -6.603694 ],
                  ['Callan Building',53.383156, -6.602664 ],
                  ['The Pheonix', 53.384368, -6.603641 ],
                  ['Engineering Building', 53.384437, -6.602444, ],
                  ['John Hume Building',53.383976, -6.600213, 4],
                  ['Arts block', 53.383739, -6.601444, 5],
                  ['Iontas', 53.384510, -6.600624, 3],
                  ['Science Building',53.383125, -6.600575 , 2],
                  ['Eoals', 53.384616, -6.601662, 1]
            ];

            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
              zoom: 16,
              center: new google.maps.LatLng(53.381567, -6.599668),
              mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            });

            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

            var marker, i;

            for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) { 
              marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
                map: map
              });

              google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
                return function() {
                  infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
                  infowindow.open(map, marker);
                }
                })(marker, i));
            }   
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to call the `map1()` function when it is not yet fully loaded. If you wait for the document to load before calling `map1` this should not happen.

```
<html>
<head>
     <script src="map.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map">

  </div>
  <script>
        window.onload = function() {
            map1();
        }
  </script>
</body >
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is you're trying to get html elements before they are loaded on the page:

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map')
```

try to wrap your whole function in js file in this code:

```
window.onload = function() {
    function map1() { ... }
}
```

but even better if you separate this into smaller functions and only set your vars on document load.